# Given the following diophantine equation: $53x + 12y = 2$ determine the integer solutions (if any).

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

The question that I am working is:

Given the following diophantine equation: $53x + 12y = 2$ determine the integer solutions (if any).

The problem that I am facing is that I tried to find two solutions but keep getting an incorrect $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$ values.

Here is my work:
Claim - "Yes, integer solutions do exists."

Using Euclid's Algorithm:

$53 = 12(4) + 5$
$12 = 5(2) + 2$
$5 = 2(2) + 1$
$1 = 1(1) + 0$

Hence, $\text{gcd}(53,12) = 1$

---

System of equations:

$1 = 2 - 1(1)$
$1 = 5 - 2(2)$
$2 = 12 - 5(2)$
$5 = 53 - 12(4)$

Comment: You have found a pair (x,y)=(1,-4).  This is present in your last equation. Are you just having problems stating all of the solutions from there?

Comment: Oops. This is from forever ago. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use basic algebra and common sense, take a look at the equation. Clearly $12y$ and $2$ are even so we have to have $53x$ even, so $x$ is even.  A quick look and $x = -2$ will give $y = 9$, and $x = 10$ will give $y = -44$, now if you get the hang of it, keep on adding or subtracting $12$ to/from $x$ and other solutions will follow. Of course lab bhattacharjee's solution is more complete and rigorous, but this is one way such things can be dealt with intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution of Linear Congruence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence) says solution always exists as $2$ is divisible by $(12,53)=1$

$$53x+12y=2=12\cdot9-2\cdot53$$

$$\iff53(x+2)=12(9-y)\iff\dfrac{53(x+2)}{12}=9-y$$ which is an integer

$\implies12|53(x+2)\iff12|(x+2)$ as $(12,53)=1$

$\implies x=12m-2$ where $m$ is any integer

Put this in $53x+12y=2$

Comment: I do not know what linear congruence is. In lecture we have not learnt it so I can't use the method presented above.I need to solve the linear equations and that is what I am having trouble with..

Comment: @Zero, The solution does not need "linear congruence theorem"(linked). It has used basic concept of algebra if you ignore the first line, right?

Comment: Yes, Im just using basic algebra nothing else.